# Change control type styling via qtquickcontrols2-configuration?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

Can I use the `qtquickcontrols2.conf` file to globally style controls such as `Buttons` and `Labels`?

For example can I do something like the following?

```
[Controls]
Style=Material

[Material]
Theme=Dark

[Material\Button]
Text=Red

[Material\Label]
Color=Red
```

The above isn't working for me. I am aware I can use the Style Singleton approach but that means I need to use the style variables in each QML document I make. It would be nicer to just change it globally something like the above if its possible.

*Also:* Certain configuration settings are not working. For example, the palette changes dont work but font changes do. Any idea why?

```
[Controls]
Style=Material

[Material]
Theme=Dark ; These changes work
Accent=Red
Palette.Base=Red  ; These changes are not applied/shown?
Palette.Text=Blue

; These changes are applied/shown
[Material\Font]
Family=Open Sans
PixelSize=20

; These changes are not applied/shown?
[Material\Palette]
Base=#000000
Text=#ffffff
```